# momentjs switching between timezone with 12 hours or more difference

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I am using moment js to convert the date to UTC like this

```
var a = moment.utc('20-Oct-2021').tz('Asia/Kolkata');

a.format()
```

This results `2021-10-20T05:30:00+05:30`

Now I am trying to use access this from Newsland that is from this timezone **Pacific/Auckland** - In system I changed my timezone to this which is +13.

Now the result for

`moment().utc(a).format()` is

`2021-10-21T02:09:12Z`

If you notice the date is 21 instead of 20 which is the actual date stored.

**Facing problem with all greater than +-12**

Comment: `moment().utc(a)` doesn't seem the right usage to me. Calling `utc()` with `moment()` has different purpose. Check https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/

Comment: @alpakyol the what would be the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your timezone doesn't change the timezone of `a` since its zone is manually set. You need to use `local()` to get the time in your timezone.

```js
// Always pass the string format if the string is not an ISO 8601 date
var a = moment.utc('20-Oct-2021', 'DD-MMM-YYYY').tz('Asia/Kolkata');

console.log(a.format());
console.log(a.utc().format()); // in UTC

console.log(a.local().format()); // This is in your timezone

a.tz("Pacific/Auckland"); // Change to Auckland

console.log(a.format()); // Auckland time
console.log(a.local().format()); // In your timezone, as same as above
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```